# Recurring micro-payments platform

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways, micropayments

I'm thinking through SaaS platform, where customers will pay little (20-50 cents) fee for daily use.
My first thought was to create own internal currency and deduct customer's balance daily.

But I'm wondering is there chance not to reinvent the money and use existing crypto-currency (bitcoin, ripple or another) environment.

So idea should be like that: customers have their own wallets and set trust-relationship to my shop/gateway for, let's say, equivalent $5 daily. And my script gathers yield and opens access to the platform.

---

Requirements are:

- lowest or zero transaction fee, as it is micro-payments
- I don't like bitcoin, because it costs a lot, and most of transactions will be ~0.0004** BTC. It's really hard to keep accuracy
- it should be easy for my customers to create and maintain wallet and to buy the currency

Comment: Your second 'requirement' is not a requirement but an nonsensical opinion.

Comment: Note there is also a [Ripple forum post](https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7645&sid=aa5f528927470f6e66a16dc7c8de6d01) about this.

Answer (score -1):

Bitcoin can do exactly that. Search for micropayment channels.

Small recurring payments with very low fees.

For example http://sourceforge.net/p/bitcoin/mailman/bitcoin-development/thread/44f8fd60-be4a-436d-a132-422b939d6de1@email.android.com/

Comment: as I can see it's client-server implementation, so all of my clients should install and keep running (java) application. Which is not my case, because all of this has sense if there are many users. Unfortunately installing apps is a blocker for most of my potential users

Comment: I'm looking for solution like: user creates a trust-link to server account for some amount only once, and it works until it is not recalled and wallet balance is positive

Comment: It's still early day in bitcoin world. A lot of stuff has been thought of but much of that still needs to be implemented. That forum post is more than a year old, so you probably want to search around some more to see what has been improved since then. I don't think the client needs to have something that keeps running. I don't know if there are any bitcoin wallets yet that support these channels though.